# Какие подводные камни есть у замыканий?

Tags: javascript, замыкания

C замыканиями я знаком, знаю как их применить.

Недавно был на собеседовании и спросили какие недостатки у замыканий есть, а я не знаю. Хотелось бы узнать какие они у замыканий.

Пример с setTimeout показывать не надо. Как они работают я понимаю.

Я гуглил, был на https://javascript.info/ и https://developer.mozilla.org/. Не нашел ответа.

Решил посетить этот источник.

Хотелось бы с примером где есть недостаток.

Или ссылку на источник, буду благодарен.

Comment: А какие подводные камни есть у оператора `*` ?) Он просто выполняет то, для чего предназначен. Как и замыкание: Просто создает дополнительную область, где можно изолированно хранить переменные и получить к ним доступ.

Comment: С замыканиями неудобно работать, сложно отлаживать

Comment: добавил про издержки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С замыканиями то всё хорошо, а вот люди несовершенны...

Вот хотел человек каждую секунду по числу, а получил 5 пятерок сразу:

```
for(var i=0;i<5;i++) {
    setTimeout(()=>console.log(i), 1000)
    console.log('privet')
}
```

1. Если замыкание передается аргументом в какую-то функцию (здесь `setTimeout`), то эта функция и определяет, когда и сколько раз будет запущено замыкание. `setTimeout` вызвался в цикле 5 раз подряд почти одновременно. Каждый вызов закидывал замыкание в будущее на 1 секунду.
   Все `console.log('privet')` сработали на секунду раньше всех `console.log(i)`.
2. `var` говорит о том, что переменная определена для окружающей функции,
   в цикле она меняется. Из замыкания будет видно текущее значение переменной.
   Т. к. все `console.log(i)` выполнятся после цикла, они увидят `i` на момент окончания цикла (когда `i` перестало подходить под условие).
3. если `var` заменить на `let`, то у каждой итерации цикла (и у каждого из 5-и созданных замыканий) будет своя `i`, и `console.log(i)` напечатает числа от 0 до 4.

Еще `this` вечно чему попало равен в `function(){`...

В `function(){` `this` не замыкается. В `this` попадает объект, который стоял до `.` при *вызове* функции: `iWillBeThisInside.fun()`, a если вызывалось просто `fun()`, то глобальный объект (часто window).

Возможно, это было настолько частой ошибкой, что при введении стрелочных функций (`=>`) сделали по-другому. Здесь `this` внутри будет такой же, как снаружи, при создании замыкания.

И всё бы хорошо, но определения методов классов ведут себя, как просто `function`. Так что, мучаемся ... используем `.bind(this)` дальше.

---

Из объективных недостатков:
У замыканий есть накладные расходы на создание и запуск. По сути, при создании замыкания создается объект. Например, `while` работает быстрее `forEach`. Эти накладные расходы могут иметь значение при оптимизации тяжелых вычислений, или хранении в памяти большого количества объектов-замыканий. Для обычного кода разница не будет заметна, и *преждевременной оптимизации* лучше избегать, отдавая предпочтение ясности (надежности) кода.

Comment: `this` - никак не связан с замыканиями

Comment: @Grundy, в том и дело; интуитивно человеку кажется, что он его замкнул

Comment: Ни одного такого не встречал

Comment: Вот 'Стрелочные функции' -- по-другому; ... Ну вот и напишите, что вы встречали. Я эти ошибки не сам выдумываю, они частые.

Comment: Если ты с чем-то сталкивался - это не значит, что все с этим сталкивались

Comment: Человек спросил про типичные ошибки (иносказательно). Я ему рассказал. Ты против чего в этой ситуации выступаешь?

Comment: Против плохого ответа, в котором из двух примеров, один без объяснений что происходит, а второй вообще не относится к вопросу.

Comment: @Grundy, так бы и сказал сразу ... подробней сделал

Comment: «Это было настолько частой ошибкой, что при введении стрелочных функций сделали по-другому» — А это где-то официально прописано? Мне-то казалось, это прикольная фишка, чтобы при использовании внешнего this внутри функции, не приходилось копировать / передавать тот this...

Comment: @OPTIMUS PRIME Это субъективные наблюдения. Просто видишь, как люди ... а потом раз, и авторы делают лучше.